# Forcing SSL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

I have a piece of code here which works and forces SSL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sharepanel.net/$1 [R,L]
```

Is there anyway to make this work with all directories except for the directory filemanager (sharepanel.net/filemanager)?

Thanks
Hrach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^filemanager(/|$) - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sharepanel.net/$1 [R,L]
```

The RewriteRule will stop the rewrites if the directory is "/filemanager/" or "/filemanager" or "/filemanager/stuff/" (but not "/filemanager-extrastuff").

Answer (score 0):

Filter using REQUEST_URI as shown below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} !^/filemanager/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sharepanel.net/$1 [R,L]
```